# No backup transports available on android emulator with api level 24+

Tags: android, backup, emulation, transport, android-backup-service

I want to test backuping of my application, but backup transport isn't available on the emulator. I tried two emulators - Android API version 24 and 25, both with Google API support. When I execute `bmgr list transports`, bmgr answers: `No transports available`. When I execute the same command on my device and emulators with lower api version, bmgr says that local transport is avaiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem affects only x86_64 emulators, on x86 API 24 emulator local transport is availabe.